# how to rebuilt a specific dependent library with /MD mode in c++ VS2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

One of my specific dependent library is built with /ML. How to rebuil it with /MD?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rebuild it**:

You need the source code and Visual C++ projects/solution used to build the library, and change the setting in the project settings.

If you don't have the VC++ projects, you can create them and configure them by hand. More work.

The worst is the case when you don't have the source code of that library... that would be a problem, because you don't have what to rebuild.

**Later edit**
Go to project properties/C++/Code Generation and select the option from there (Runtime library).

Comment: yeah, I have the source code and the solution project. How to rebuil it with /MD? Thanks mate! :D